# How to protect generated inline cells from editing?

Tags: cells, input, inline, tex

I want to protect generated inline cell (which contains TeX source) from attempts to edit, since any attempt to regenerate box structure will fail. In particular, suppose in a text cell one creates inline cell (with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>) in which, in turn, one tries to put some TeX formula (press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + dollar sign). For example, try simple input a\w b . Since at the moment there are no command \w after you exit the input box you will see just a b. Now if your edit `.../Mathematica/13.x.x/SystemFiles/IncludeFiles/TEXImport/latex.tnb` file (make a reserve copy!) and append in the end of it the line (I inserted it between lines \input datetime.tnc and `\makeatother` of that file)

```tex
\def\w{\wedge}
```

and then once more enter and exit the inline cell, the content will be automatically reprocessed an nice a [Wedge] b structure will appear. Since I plan to share that notebook a user can accidentally enter the inline cell. After it exits the inline cell the output will be broken. How to protect from such an accident?

Comment: I wonder if the [Editable](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Editable.html) attribute can be set to False for an inline cell.

Comment: @GustavoDelfino It can't be set (otherwise I would not ask for help), however, the inline cell contains other containers like FormBox. Also there might be some specific solution to prevent auto generation of content in texinput mechanism itself. At the moment I am not sure that solution is not possible.

Comment: I just did small test by manually adding the option using "Show Expression" and it worked. However, I know that this is easier said than done for a large cell.

Comment: @GustavoDelfino For me it don't work. For example, take this: Cell[TextData[{
 "\nThis ir text cell with tex inlined cell  ",
 Cell[BoxData[
  FormBox[
   TemplateBox[<|"boxes" -> FormBox[
       RowBox[{
         StyleBox["a", "TI"], "+", 
         StyleBox["b", "TI"], "+", 
         StyleBox["s", "TI"]}], TraditionalForm], "errors" -> {}, "input" -> 
     "a+b+s", "state" -> "Boxes"|>,
    "TeXAssistantTemplate"], TraditionalForm]],
  Editable->False]
}], "Text"]    Despite I set Editable->False to the inlined cell I can edit it. What is your example?

Comment: The issue is with the Editable attribute not being respected for the boxes in your comment above. But it has nothing to do with subcells. Use CellPrint on you inner Cell and it remains editable.

Comment: @GustavoDelfino If you open option inspector (menu Format/Option inspector) and there select Global Preferences and order items By Category then looking at Cell Options and then  Inline Cell Options, then you will immediately see that only two options can be given for inline cells : CellBaseline and CellSize. There are no possibility to provide Editable.

Comment: I'll post what I have as an "answer" to see if somebody else can help you further.

Comment: @GustavoDelfino Just want to inform you, that I contacted Wolfram support and they answered that  " a work around is currently not available". So, sadly, seems the task at the moment don't have a positive solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer. It is just too much code for a comment. The following code generates a cell, *without any subcells*. This cell has an `Editable -> False` option as well as the internal `TemplateBox`. Yet, the output is editable. Does anyone know why?

```
Cell[
    BoxData[
        FormBox[
            TemplateBox[
                <|
                    "boxes" -> FormBox[ 
                                  RowBox[
                                      {
                                          StyleBox["a", "TI"],
                                          "+",
                                          StyleBox["b", "TI"],
                                          "+",
                                          StyleBox["s", "TI"]
                                      }
                                  ],
                                  TraditionalForm
                              ],
                    "errors" -> {},
                    "input" -> "a+b+s",
                    "state" -> "Boxes"
                |>,
                "TeXAssistantTemplate",
                Editable -> False
            ],
            StandardForm
        ]
    ],
    Editable->False
 ] // CellPrint
```